# Failed prop type: Invalid prop of type `array` , expected `object`

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

This is how my data looks like:
[image]

This is how my type checking looks like:

```
SingleProduct.propTypes = {
  product: PropTypes.shape({
    title: PropTypes.string,
    description: PropTypes.string,
    images: PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        original: PropTypes.string,
      })
    ),
    specification: PropTypes.string,
    price: PropTypes.number
  }),
  
};
```

I get this warning:

```
 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `product` of type `array` supplied to `SingleProduct`, expected `object`.
```

What is wrong with my type checking?

Comment: Are you sure the problem's in the type *checking*? Do you *want* to pass an object rather than an array?

Comment: When I pass PropTypes.any warning is gone

Comment: ...because then it's not checking the types at all.

Comment: Yea this is because you are passing product prop an array instead of an object. Issue is not with propTypes

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I deleted the .arrayOf() and just declared the shape in my nested value. So in your code try this:

```
images: PropTypes.shape({
        original: PropTypes.string,
      }),
```